# ways to make a physics engine

Tags: physics, 3d-meshes, particles

Hey so i've been looking into real time physics engines, which led me to the crazy[Laggoa multiphysics engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuWuTc5agVA&wl_token=wuiDGtBIHzqOYVe23uzps-YQzzl8MTMwNzUxMjU1NUAxMzA3NDI2MTU1&wl_id=MuWuTc5agVA) by thiaga costa, and brought up the question of:

**What are some possible ways, ideas that have or have not already been done to make a real time physics engine? How about non-real time?**

I know the Lagoa engine uses meshes and a crapload of particles... and then there's the rigid body way of going about things.....
Also i'm only at 2d level in creating games right now so any 2d physics ideas would be great too!

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking here. You want a list of ideas? Ways to write a physics-engine? Quite a broad topic. Community Wiki is probably a suitable format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) was written as a tutorial on how to write 2D physics engines. The site contains links to a lot of presentations on how the algorithms work and how to make it efficient.

You might also want to look into this [presentation](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1012447/Go-With-the-Flow-Fluid) done by the Pixeljunk Shooter team, describing how they did 2D fluids.

If you are interesed in 3D, read [Realtime Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/).

For more cutting edge offline physics [this](http://www.autodeskresearch.com/pdf/nucleus.pdf) might be a good presentation. It describes how a new solver was developed for Maya, and I remember our physics programmer going nuts over it some years ago.